# Which algebraic relations are possible between algebraic conjugates?

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials

For which non-constant rational functions $f(x)$ in $\mathbb{Q}(x)$ is there $\alpha$, algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$, such that $\alpha$ and $f(\alpha) \neq \alpha$ are algebraic conjugates? More generally, can one describe the set of such $\alpha$ (empty/non-empty, finite/infinite etc.) if one is given $f$?

Examples:

- $f(x)=-x$: These are precisely the square roots of algebraic numbers $\beta$ such that there is no square root of $\beta$ in $\mathbb{Q}(\beta)$. There are infinitely many $\alpha$ and even infinitely many of degree $2$.
- $f(x)=x^2$: These are precisely the roots of unity of odd order, since $H(\alpha)=H(\alpha^2)=H(\alpha)^2$ implies $H(\alpha)=1$, so $\alpha$ a root of unity. Here $H(\alpha)$ is the absolute multiplicative Weil height of $\alpha$. There are infinitely many $\alpha$, but only finitely many of degree $\leq D$ for any $D$.
- $f(x)=x+1$: There is no $\alpha$. If there was and $P(x)$ was its minimal polynomial, then $P(x+1)$ would be another irreducible polynomial, vanishing at $\alpha$, with the same leading coefficient and hence $P(x+1)=P(x)$. Looking at the coefficients of the second highest power of $x$ now leads to a contradiction. Analogously for $f(x)=x+a$ if $a$ is any non-zero rational number.

So the existence of such an $\alpha$ and the set of all possible $\alpha$ seem to depend rather intricately on $f(x)$, which seems interesting to me. As I found no discussion of this question in the literature, I post it here.

UPDATE: Firstly thanks to all who have contributed so far! As Eric Wofsey pointed out, any solution $\alpha$ will satisfy $f^n(\alpha)=\alpha$ for some $n>1$, where $f^n$ is the $n$-th iterate of $f$. So one should consider solutions of the equation $f^n(x)-x=0$ or $f^p(x)-x=0$ for $p$ prime.

If the degree of $f$ is at least 2, one can always find irrational such solutions $\alpha$ with $f(\alpha) \neq \alpha$ by the answer of Joe Silverman. However, for his proof to work, we'd need to know that $f^k(\alpha)$ and $\alpha$ are conjugate for some $k$ with $0 < k <p$. I'm not enough of an expert to follow through with his hints for proving this, but if someone does, I'd be very happy about an answer!

If the degree of $f$ is 1, then $f$ is a Möbius transformation and all $f^n$ will have the same fixed points as $f$ (so there's no solution) unless $f$ is of finite order. In that case, if $f(x) \neq x$, the order is 2, 3, 4 or 6 (see http://home.wlu.edu/~dresdeng/papers/nine.pdf). By the same reference, in the latter three cases, $f$ is conjugate to $\frac{-1}{x+1}$, $\frac{x-1}{x+1}$ or $\frac{2x-1}{x+1}$, so it suffices to consider these $f$, which give rise to the minimal polynomials $x^3-nx^2-(n+3)x-1$ (closely related to the polynomial in GNiklasch's answer), $x^4+nx^3-6x^2-nx+1$ and $x^6-2nx^5+5(n-3)x^4+20x^3-5nx^2+2(n-3)x+1$, if my calculations are correct. If the order is 2, the map is of the form $\frac{-x+a}{bx+1}$ or $\frac{a}{x}$, which leads to $x^2+(bn-a)x+n$ or $x^2+nx+a$ respectively. So this case is somewhat degenerate, which explains the unusual behavior of $f(x)=-x$ and $f(x)=x+1$ above.

Comment: Looking at the "Related" questions: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/53610/which-polynomials-arise-as-formulas-for-a-conjugate?rq=1 Note that it requires $\deg(\alpha)=\deg(f)+1$, and so in particular $f(x)=x^2$ is not applicable in that setting.

Comment: Clearly the orbit of $\alpha$ when you iterate $f$ must be finite, which gives a simpler argument for your last two examples.

Comment: Have a look at http://www.mif.vu.lt/~jonajank/files/linear.pdf (not same, but related)

Answer (score 16):

A first observation is that the field $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ must admit a non-identity automorphism $\sigma$, since applying a rational function to $\alpha$ will not take us outside this field. Given such $\alpha$ and $\sigma$, you can immediately read off an $f$ by expressing $\sigma(\alpha)$ as a $\mathbb{Q}$-linear combination of $1, \alpha, \alpha^2,\ldots$, and there'll be additional non-polynomial (rational) expressions in terms of $\alpha$. This leads to plenty of examples, but now we want to turn this around and start from a given $f$.

Next, the application of $f$ can be iterated. If $g$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over the rationals, $g \circ f$ will be a rational function whose numerator vanishes at $\alpha$, hence is divisible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ by $g$, hence vanishes at $f(\alpha)$ as well, so $g(f(f(\alpha))) = (g\circ f)(f(\alpha))=0$, so $f(f(\alpha))$ is another conjugate of $\alpha$, and so forth.

Since there are only finitely many conjugates to choose from, some iterate $f^{\circ n}(\alpha)$ must return to $\alpha$: in other words, $\alpha$ will be a root of (the numerator of) $f^{\circ n}(x)-x$ for some integer $n > 1$. (This leads to another argument ruling out $f(x)=x+1$ and friends, as has been noted in the comments.)

So in many cases you'll be able, given $f$, to find the $\alpha$ by picking an $n$ and factoring the numerator of $f^{\circ n}(x)-x$ into irreducible polynomials.

However, the $n$-th iterate of $f$ might be the identity function $x\in \mathbb{Q}(x)$ *already*, and the numerator to be factored might thus be zero! This happens in your first example $f(x)=-x$ with $n=2$, or with $$f(x)=1/x$$ again with $n=2$ which leads to reciprocal minimal polynomials $g(x)=x^{\mathrm{deg}(g)}g(1/x)$, or with (e.g.) $$f(x)=1-1/x$$ with $n=3$ which gives rise (among other things) to what D. Shanks in 1974 called *The Simplest Cubic Fields* ([Math.Comp. **28**, 1137-1152](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1974-28-128/S0025-5718-1974-0352049-8/S0025-5718-1974-0352049-8.pdf)), with $g(x)=x^3+ax^2-(a+3)x+1$. Here, you can proceed by prescribing a degree for $g$, spelling out the condition that $g$ should divide the numerator of $g\circ f$, and comparing coefficients.

Answer (score 9):

The answer to the question you ask, namely "for which $f(x)$...?", is that there exists such an $\alpha$ for every $f(x)$ of degree at least $2$. Proof: If $p$ is a sufficiently large prime, then there is a $p$-periodic point $\alpha$ of $f(x)$ that is not in $\mathbb Q$. (This follows, e.g., by computing heights.) So $f^p(\alpha)=\alpha$ 
and $f(\alpha)\ne\alpha$. The orbit $\{f^i(\alpha):0\le i<p\}$ is Galois invariant [*not necessarily true, see below*] and contains an element $\alpha$ not in $\mathbb Q$, so there is some $\sigma\in\text{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb Q}/\mathbb Q)$ such that $\sigma(\alpha)=f^k(\alpha)$ for some $1\le k<p$. Now let $j$ satisfy $jk\equiv1\pmod{p}$. Then
$$ f(\alpha) = f^{jk}(\alpha)
   = \underbrace{f^k\circ\cdots\circ f^k }_{\text{$j$ iterates}}(\alpha)
  = \sigma^j(\alpha).
$$
This shows that $f(\alpha)$ is a Galois conjugate of $\alpha$.

For your second question, as has been noted, if $f(\alpha)=\sigma(\alpha)$, then since $\sigma$ has finite order, one must have that $\alpha$ is a periodic point for iteration of $f$. So your question seems to come down to more-or-less classifying all irrational numbers that are periodic (but not fixed) for a given $f(x)\in\mathbb{Q}(x)$. There's been a lot of study of the  Galois properties of fields generated by periodic points of rational functions. See Section 3.9 of *The Arithmetic of Dynamical Systems* (Springer GTM 241) for an introduction and some further references.

--- ADDITION ---

As Gabriel Dill pointed out, it is the set of points of period $p$ that is invariant under Galois, not the individual orbits. In general, the Galois group $G_p$ of the points of period $p$ is a subgroup of a wreath product $W_p$ of a cyclic group $C_p$ and a symmetric group $S_N$, where $N_p=(d^p-d)/p$. [This is assuming that the $p$-periodic points don't appear with multiplicities.] It is conjectured (I believe) that $G_p=W_p$ for all but finitely many $p$ (except maybe for $x^d$, Chebyshev, and Lattes maps?). This would certainly be enough. Alternatively, if one could find primes with $p\nmid N_p$, then it would suffice to know that $p\mid\#G_p$. (Of course, even for $d=2$ we don't know how to find infinitely many such primes.) Clearly one can get away with making various weaker assumptions about $G_p$, and possibly they could be proven.

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand your argument. Take e.g. $f(x)=x^2$ and $p=3$. Then $\alpha=\exp(2\pi i/7)$ is irrational with $f^p(\alpha)=\alpha$ and $f(\alpha) \neq \alpha$. But the orbit of $\alpha$ isn't Galois invariant (it contains only 3 elements). It still contains at least one conjugate of $\alpha$, different from $\alpha$, which is the important thing, but why does this hold in general?

Comment: @GabrielDill Sorry, you're right. The complete set of $p$-periodic points is a Galois invariant set (this is obvious), it breaks up into disjoint orbits of size $p$, so one needs to find an element of Galois that maps one of the orbits to itself, but doesn't fix the orbit. So that makes things a little trickier. The Galois group is a subgroup of a wreath product of a cyclic group $C_p$ and a permutation groups $S_N$ for an appropriate $N$. I withdraw my answer as a complete proof, but will edit it to indicate how one might proceed.